# State space of $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, locally-convex-spaces, convex-hulls

Consider the $C^*$-algebra $A := C(X)$, where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Denote by $S(A)$ the state space of $A$. In the weak$^*$ topology this is a convex compact set such that $S(A)$ is the closed convex hull of its extreme points. By using the Riesz-Kakutani representation theorem it is easy to see that the pure states (extreme points of $S(A)$) are exactly the point evaluations.

Is there an adhoc proof of this fact ?

Comment: Which fact do you mean? That the pure states on $C(X)$ are exactly the point evaluations?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is a pure state, then the corresponding representation $\pi_{\varphi}$ must be one-dimensional (since $C(X)$ is commutative). Hence, $\ker(\pi_{\varphi})$ is a maximal ideal, which must coincide with the set of functions that vanish at a point. Hence, $\varphi$ must be the evaluation at that point.